# Calling scala from R (using jvmr)

Tags: r, scala, jvm

I tried to integrate some scala-code into R ... unfortunately, I failed:

myself@mycomputer:~/$ R

```
library("jvmr")

a <- scalaInterpreter()
```

Error in .jcall(.jnew("org.ddahl.jvmr.impl.RScalaInterpreter$"), "Lorg/ddahl/jvmr/impl/RScalaInterpreter;",  : 
  java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.tools.nsc.settings.MutableSettings$BooleanSetting cannot be cast to scala.reflect.internal.settings.MutableSettings$SettingValue

Any idea? Doing the same with Java `(b <- javaInterpreter())` works.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to run Scala code outside R? Is the Scala package object on a path available to R?

Comment: Yes, I can start the scala-Interpreter outside R.The scala-Compiler works also fine. I don't know if the scala package are available to R ... they are at least available on the system path, so I can start the interpreter from everywhere ...